# How to change the value of a varible in _variable.scss?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, sass

I have a website with multiple colors.
and i have a variable defined in _variable.scss $theme_color:red;

How can i change the value of that variable to $theme_color:blue; in _variable.scss? while i add class blue to the

Is there any possible way to do so?

Comment: If you have a Sass/SCSS question then why are you adding Less in the tag list?

Comment: its because i would be happy if that can be done even with LESS

Comment: Then maybe you should make your question more generic (or) state this in the question itself. Otherwise, the presence of an extra tag will confuse users.

Comment: okay. Do you have a solution for Less or Sass way?

Comment: My suggestion would be to use separate variables file for each theme and then statically generate the required classes or maybe something like [this](http://lesscss.org/less-preview/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22%40theme-color%3A%20blue%3B%5Cn.some-class%7B%5Cn%20%20color%3A%20%40theme-color%3B%5Cn%7D%5Cn%5Cnbody.some-other-theme%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%40theme-color%3A%20red%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%2F%2F%20instead%20of%20writing%20the%20below%20again%2C%20you%20could%20import%20the%20file%5Cn%20%20.some-class%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20color%3A%20%40theme-color%3B%5Cn%20%20%7D%5Cn%7D%22%7D).

Answer (score 0):

in root file main.scss use :

```
@import '_variable.scss'; // import variables file
$theme_color:blue; // new color
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [`!default`](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#variable_defaults_) keyword.

### With `!default`

```
/* @file _variable.scss */
$theme_color: red !default;
$theme_shadow: 1px 1px 2px $theme_color !default;

/* @file styles.scss */
@import 'variable';
.foo {
  color: $theme_color;
  box-shadow: $theme_shadow;
}

/* @file corporate.scss */
// I override the color BEFORE the loading of my variables declaration.
$theme_color: blue;
@import 'variable';

.foo {
  color: $theme_color;
  box-shadow: $theme_shadow;
}    
// Specific rule
.corporate-thing {
  box-shadow: $theme_shadow;
}
```

**CSS output**

```
/* @file styles.scss */
.foo {
  color: red;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px red;
}

/* @file corporate.scss */
.foo {
  color: blue;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px blue;
}

.corporate-thing {
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px blue;
}
```

### Without `!default`

If you do not use `!default`, the variable is overwritten at each call of `_variable.scss`:

```
/* @file _variable.scss */
$theme_color: red;
$theme_shadow: 1px 1px 2px $theme_color;

/* @file styles.scss */
@import 'variable';
.foo {
  color: $theme_color;
  box-shadow: $theme_shadow;
}

/* @file corporate.scss */
$theme_color: blue;

// Now, $theme_color will be overwritten with the `red` value
// because of the absence of the `!default` keyword.
@import 'variable';

.foo {
  color: $theme_color;
  box-shadow: $theme_shadow;
}    
// Specific rule
.corporate-thing {
  box-shadow: $theme_shadow;
}
```

**CSS output**

```
/* @file styles.scss */
.foo {
  color: red;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px red;
}

/* @file corporate.scss */
.foo {
  color: red;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px red;
}    
.corporate-thing {
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px red;
}
```

### Final wrong case: change the color after loading `_variable.scss`

```
/* @file _variable.scss */
$theme_color: red;
$theme_shadow: 1px 1px 2px $theme_color;

/* @file styles.scss */
@import 'variable';
.foo {
  color: $theme_color;
  box-shadow: $theme_shadow;
}

/* @file corporate.scss */
@import 'variable';
$theme_color: blue; // AFTER

.foo {
  color: $theme_color;
  // In this case, $theme_shadow is not overwritten with the new value
  // of $theme_color and keeps it value to 'red'.
  box-shadow: $theme_shadow;
}    
// Specific rule
.corporate-thing {
  box-shadow: $theme_shadow;
}
```

**CSS output**

```
/* @file styles.scss */
.foo {
  color: red;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px red;
}

/* @file corporate.scss */
.foo {
  color: blue; // OK: blue
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px red; // KO: red
}    
.corporate-thing {
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px red; // KO: red
}
```

### BONUS

In fact, you can directly import `styles.scss` from `corporate.scss`:

```
/* @file _variable.scss */
$theme_color: red !default;
$theme_shadow: 1px 1px 2px $theme_color !default;

/* @file styles.scss */
@import 'variable';
.foo {
  color: $theme_color;
  box-shadow: $theme_shadow;
}

/* @file corporate.scss */
// I override the color BEFORE the loading of my main stylesheet
$theme_color: blue;

// Now I have to generate the same code that `style.css`, so the
// easiest way to do it is to directly import it.
@import 'styles';

// Specific rule
.corporate-thing {
  box-shadow: $theme_shadow;
}
```